# zoomus:// fb:// "net::err_unknown_url_scheme" in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I don't know java. I used a code from internet for my android app to view my website using webview. On clicking links to Facebook or Zoom, it showed the "net::err_unknown_url_scheme" error window and freezes. I needed to restart the app. I have searched the internet including this website and tried the suggested solutions. But these showed syntax errors in Android Studio. Maybe the solution codes are not compatible with my codes. My mainactivity.java is as below. I would truly appreciate your help.

```
package com.dhammalaan.dl;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import com.google.dl.R;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String websiteURL = "https://google.com/"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {

            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

        }
        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }

        );

    }



    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        //Keep webview in app when clicking links
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }

    };


    //set back button functionality
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
        } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}


class CheckNetwork {

    private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)

    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)

                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null)

        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");

            return false;

        }
        else
        {

            if(info.isConnected())

            {

                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");

                return true;

            }

            else

            {

                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked up the internet (stackoverflow site also) and tried the suggested solutions but these showed syntax errors in Android Studio. Maybe the solutions do not match with my codes. Would appreciate your expert help.